# Working in a SQL database, is there a way to convert a float to a nvarchar without converting the float to scientific notation?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm building a database from scratch. Currently I have an Excel sheet that is massive and can't really work due to the amount of data stored. I'm using a SQL Server database to store the data.

Right now, all but one of the columns I use work. There is an ID that I need to use in the majority of my database. Unfortunately, half the IDs are alphanumeric and have are numbers (no letters). To get the data from Excel to SQL Server, I stored half the data as `float` and the other half as `NVARCHAR`.  Once the data was out of Excel, I created a third column and combined the data using the code seen below:

```
UPDATE dbo.Table
SET ID = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), ISNULL(NumID, N'')) + N'' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), ISNULL(LetID, N''))
```

After running the code, I've created a new problem. The numeric data is now written as "4.01867e+007" rather than "40186720".

Does anyone know why or how to fix this? I would like the data to read as "40186720" rather than have letters to make it easier to use.

Comment: There may be a solution specific to the database, e.g. SQL Server, and version, e.g. 2012, that you are using. Care to share? [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is available in SQL Server 2012. Alternatively, using `Convert` to change the value to a [precise numeric type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) before converting to a string ought to work.

Comment: HABO, I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Why, pray tell, did you choose `float` as a rational (pun intended) data type for part of an identification? Wouldn't an integer data type do?

Comment: @HABO I made the mistake of not doing more to change the data when I imported it from excel.  Getting it to put the data into SQL is very poorly designed.  I got it to work as a float, it's super quirky and not great.

Comment: Did you use a [`float`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) with enough precision to store the digits in your identifications? A `float` needs more than 24-bits to store the 8 significant digits in your example ("40186720"), otherwise you've lost some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the numeric part will be between ±9 quintillion (actually 9,223,372,036,854,775,807), then you can convert your float to bigint before casting to text:

```
UPDATE dbo.Table
SET ID = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), ISNULL(convert(bigint,NumID), N'')) + N'' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), ISNULL(LetID, N''))
```

Comment: This worked for the project.  Thanks a lot.  I now know better than to use a float 

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `CAST`?  `CONVERT` has an optional style parameter which when left blank (depending on your DB) is probably set to a default value causing the issue...

Comment: Changed the code to: SET ID = CAST(ISNULL(LetID, N'') AS NVARCHAR(255)) + N'' + CAST(ISNULL(NumID, N'') AS NVARCHAR(255))

Comment: Right, sorry, forgot to update the functions haha... did it work?